# How to capture Rsync temp files?

Tags: linux, backup, rsync

I want to use Rsync to do incremental backup, and my aim is to store the latest change separately. I found Rsync has a temp file path to store the change, but it automatically delete the temp file when it finishes backup. So my question is that is it possible to capture the Rsync temp files and how can I do that?

Any help would be grateful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Batch mode can be used to generate a change set.

Take a look at the BATCH MODE section of the man page and the command line switches `--write-batch` and `--read-batch`.

Comment: FYI: The rsync man page has a section called "BATCH MODE" that gives more details.

Comment: Made it work by using --write-batch ! Now a new problem is that how can I combine the new created file into the original backup files to make it like restoring backup files? I found the new file has lots of special characters in it, so i'm worried about whether the new file can work with the original backup files?